# Best way to implement notification alerts in Node/Express app?

Tags: node.js, express, axios, pug

I have inherited a **Node/Express** code base and my task is to implement a notification alert in the navigation menu. The app database has a table of 'pending accounts', and the alert needs to expose the number of these pending accounts. When an account is 'approved' or 'denied', this notification alert needs to update and reflect the new total of pending accounts.

I know how to do the styling and html here, my question is how best to instantiate, maintain and pass a **global dynamic variable** that reflects the number of pending accounts, and how to get this variable exposed in the header view which contains the navbar where the notification is to be displayed.

This project a pretty standard Node/Express app, however it uses the view engine **Pug**. At the root of the view hierarchy is a layout.pug file, which loads most of the scripts and stylesheets, and this layout view in turn loads the header Pug view. When this header view loads, and every time it loads, I need this updated 'pending accounts count' value available to insert into the header view. This is what I am at a bit of a loss on how to go about.

Below is the layout.pug markup with the inclusion of the header pug view. Everything else in the project is pretty straightforward vanilla Node/Express I believe, but I am not very experienced with this stack so if any other code is needed please don't hesitate to ask and I will post. Thanks.

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    meta(http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible', content='IE=edge')
    meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no')
    meta(name='theme-color', content='#4DA5F4')
    meta(name='csrf-token', content=_csrf)

    script(src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js")

    block head

  body
    include partials/header
```

I tried including a script in my `header.pug` view, which contains the **navbar** element that I want to append the notification too...

```
link(href='/css/header/header.css' rel='stylesheet')
script(src='/js/registration/registrationsTable.js')

...
```

Which would run the following function on DOM load....

```
function getNumberOfPendingRegistrations() {
  axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: '/admin/getNumberOfPendingRegistrations'
  }).then((response) => {
    if (response.status === 200) {
      const { numPendingUsers } = response.data;
      console.log(response.data);
    } else {
      console.log(response.status);
    }
  })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}


(() => {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    getNumberOfPendingRegistrations();
```

which would then call the following express function....

```
exports.getNumberOfPendingRegistrations = (req, res) => {
  RegisteredUser.find({ status: 'PENDING' }, (err, allPendingUsers) => {
    if (!err) {
      let numPendingUsers = 0;
      allPendingUsers.forEach(() => {
        numPendingUsers++;
      });
      return res.send(200, { numPendingUsers });
    }
    console.log('error');
    throw err;
  });
};
```

which would then return `numPendingUsers` to the axios `then()` function and make that variable available to the `header.pug` view here....

```
 li.nav-item
                    a.nav-link(href='/admin/registeredUsers') 
                      span.fa-solid.fa-pen-to-square(style="font-size: 0.7em;") 
                        span(style="margin-left: 0.1em;")  Registrations
                        span.notification=numPendingUsers
```

`NumPendingUsers` returns correctly to the axios .`then()` promise, but is somehow never made available in the `header.pug` view. It is always undefined. I'm not sure if its a timing issue w when the DOM is loaded, or if I'm making the variable available in .then() incorrecly or what. And also I feel like there must be a simpler way to accomplish all of this.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that I simply needed to implement a middleware to pass this data to every route. Duh.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).